# Sequential Search not working in C

Tags: c, string, char

I'm trying to use a function to compare 2 strings:

```
void pesquisa_sequencial (trabalho *v, int max_vetor, char *pesq[]){
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < max_vetor; i++) {
    if ((strcmp(v[i].nome1,pesq[MAX]) == 0)  || (strcmp(v[i].nome2,pesq[MAX]) == 0)){
        printf("\n");
        printf("Nome: %s\n",pesq[MAX]);
        printf("Nota: %d\n",v[i].nota);
    }
    printf("\nNome %s não encontrado na lista.\n", pesq[MAX]);
  }
}
```

"trabalho *v" is the strcut that a use on my .h

```
typedef struct trabalho {
  int nota;
  char nome1[MAX], nome2[MAX];
} trabalho;
```

pesq is a char variable on my main code:

```
char pesq[MAX];
MAX = 100.
```

And "max_vetor" is the size of my vetor

But when i compile the code i have this menssages:

> main.c:150:55: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pesquisa_sequencial’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>            pesquisa_sequencial (vetor, numero_trabalhos, pesq);
>
> main.c:78:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
>   void pesquisa_sequencial (trabalho *v, int max_vetor, char *pesq[]){

Line 150

```
case 5:
    printf("Digite o nome a ser pesquisado: \n");
    scanf("%s", &pesq[MAX]);
    pesquisa_sequencial (vetor, numero_trabalhos, pesq);
    break;
```

Comment: The bug is on main.c line 150. You didn't include that line. Please include a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: Now we need to see how `pesq` is declared. Keep in mind that `char *pesq[]` (the 3rd argument to `pesquisa_sequencial()`) is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove your extra `*`

```
void pesquisa_sequencial (trabalho *v, int max_vetor, char pesq[MAX]);
```

And you call of scanf is bad change to this:

```
scanf("%99s", pesq); // MAX - 1
```